# Incorrect allocation of memory with an array of structures

Tags: c++

I have posted this problem before but I cannot seem to find a solution. So I am posting again with refined description in hopes of solving this problem. Your help is much appreciated.

What I would like to do is read in a row from a text file. This text file contains 3 types of rows:

1. A row containing the word "start" indicating the start of a particular test case result
2. Rows containing the word PASS or FAIL or PWU or FWU and accompanying data
3. A row containing the word "stop" indicating the end of a test case result

The trouble I am having is with `dataRowPointer`. `dataRowPointer` is an array of struct. It's pointer was declared in the main function, and it was passed into the following function by reference.

When I call `*dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET];`, I can see in the debugger that the first array element, dataRowPointer[0] was properly allocated in memory. However the second, third and all other elements were not properly allocated because the debugger displays them as 0xcccccccc in memory.

This is affecting my other function call `getDataRow( line, loc, tcsPointer, dataRowPointer );` which contains lines similar to `(*dataRowPointer)[dataRowIndex].tcSetNum = testCaseSetID;` .

```
void getRow( std::istream& myfile, HeaderLocations* loc, TestCaseSet* tcsPointer, DataRow** dataRowPointer )
{
            std::string line;
            std::string word;
            int currentLoc = 0;
            bool startStop = true;

            std::getline( myfile, line);
            std::stringstream sline(line);

            while ( sline >> word )
            {
                if ( word == "PASS" || word == "PWU" || word == "FWU" || word == "FAIL" )
                {   
                       startStop = false;
                       break;   
                }
                else if( word == "start" )
                {   
                        dataRowIndex = 0;
                    *dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET];
                        initializeDataRowPointer( dataRowPointer );

                    testCaseSetID = captureTestCaseSetNumber( line, tcsPointer );
                    getHeaderRow( myfile, loc );

                    startStop = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if ( word == "stop" )
                {   tcsNumber++;

                    *dataRowPointer = NULL;
                    startStop = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {   startStop = false;  }
            }

            if( !startStop )
            {   
                (*dataRowPointer)[dataRowIndex].tcSetNum = testCaseSetID;
                getDataRow( line, loc, tcsPointer, dataRowPointer );
                dataRowIndex++;
            }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I understand my code is fragile ( what if text document doesn't have start, or stop or etc), and it contains bad code (use of global variables, etc). But please I just want to solve this problem first before moving on. And please try to ignore the `*dataRowPointer = NULL;` within the `else if` statement, I will change this to something much more useful once this bug is fixed.

**EDIT** As requested the code for struct DataRow and the code for function InitializeDataRowPointer:

DataRow:

```
struct DataRow
{
    std::string tcSetNum;
    std::string class_PassFail;
    std::string rfPort;
    float temp;
    float margin;
};
```

InitializeDataRowPointer:

```
void initializeDataRowPointer( DataRow** dataRowPointer )
{
    DataRow newDataRow = {"a", "a", "a", 0.0, 0.0 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET; i++ )
    {   (*dataRowPointer)[i] = newDataRow;  }
}
```

Comment: Please show: class definition and default constructor for `DataRow`, definition of `initializeDataRowPointer`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the code you've shown ought to work; witness this program, which does work.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

#define MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET 10

struct DataRow
{
  std::string tcSetNum;
  std::string class_PassFail;
  std::string rfPort;
  float temp;
  float margin;
};

static void
initializeDataRowPointer(DataRow** dataRowPointer)
{
  DataRow newDataRow = { "a", "a", "a", 0.0, 0.0 };
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET; i++)
    (*dataRowPointer)[i] = newDataRow;
}

static void
f(DataRow** dataRowPointer)
{
  *dataRowPointer = new DataRow[MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET];
  initializeDataRowPointer(dataRowPointer);
}

int
main(void)
{
  DataRow *ptr;
  f(&ptr);

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_DATA_ROWS_PER_TEST_CASE_SET; i++)
    std::printf("%d %s %s %s %f %f\n", i,
                ptr[i].tcSetNum.c_str(),
                ptr[i].class_PassFail.c_str(),
                ptr[i].rfPort.c_str(),
                ptr[i].temp,
                ptr[i].margin);

  return 0;
}
```

I conclude that the problem is elsewhere, and I think your best bet is to take your full program and progressively delete code from it until you have the smallest possible program that still demonstrates the problem.  Once you have that, if the problem isn't obvious, ask a new question, using this smaller program as your example code.  We're much more likely to be able to help you then.